# How to make vscode autocomplete HTML tag's attribute with single quote?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

As I prefer single quote in HTML, how can I configure my VScode editor to autocomplete HTML tag's attribute's value string with single quotes?

I've tried installing `Prettier` and set `"prettier.singleQuote": true`

or set

```
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
```

or set configs for `Emmet`:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
    }
}
```

But these options won't affect HTML auto-completion.

So when I type something like: `<meta charset=` and hit `Enter` VScode will complete with double quotes:

```
<meta charset=""
```

How to get the result like:

```
<meta charset=''
```

Comment: It looks like there's been some people requesting that as an addition to VSCode on GitHub. Not sure if it's been implemented yet, however it seems like no. Here's the link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43225

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I think that issue belongs to TypeScript repo. And MS team closed that issue after adding `"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"` and 
`"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"` configs. So I'm wondering if I'm missing some corresponding config for HTML?

Comment: My bad, I totally missed the TypeScript category. Doing too many things at once I guess. I'll look for an HTML solution, but I gotta say, i'm coming up empty so far.

Comment: Sorry, you said you already added `"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",` to your settings.json file? The typescript page suggested adding it to tslint.json, so i'm just wondering if using settings.json will cover HTML.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you for your effort and precious time! For that option, I've tried setups with that or without that. And that option seems won't affect HTML auto-complete.

Comment: Damn, that was the best I had. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Ok. Last thing. I'm sure this is stupid, and you've already done it, but I just feel the need to cover all bases. You said you installed prettier - did you then subsequently enable it through settings? Again - i'm sure you have, but this has caught some people.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes, I've enabled it. (And of course, I think it's a necessary concern to check that point, too. Not embarrassing at all. XD) By the way, Emmet config won't work for this case, too.

Comment: What linter are you using?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I didn't use any special extensions in my VScode, nor any linter for HTML, yet.

Comment: Well then, if there is a solution, it is completely eluding me for now. I'll keep my eye out.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Maybe it'll be better to file an feature request to VScode team now...

Comment: Same problem here! If I write `html:5` it (emmet?) autocomplets with single quotes alright, but if I write `<div class=...` it expands to double quotes.

Comment: Anyone got an answer yet? It's 2021 and there is no solution I found on internet for quote type setting in vscode on html file. I sometimes need to switch between vscode and intellij. Intellij can keep html file as single quote but vscode couldn't. Very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new setting just merged into Insiders v1.62:

`html.completion.attributeDefaultValue`

with the options: `empty | singleQuotes | doubleQuotes`

`doubleQuotes` is the default.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/129284 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/8d70e049dd1f15ce1f4a114c801b71aa9183c00b

[image: attribute quotes setting - single, double or none]