# VSCode tab complete doesn't include equals for attributes

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tab-completion

In VSCode, when I want to add an attribute to an HTML element I can start typing it and then press tab to complete the attribute name. But when I do that, it doesn't include the equals (=) symbol.

When I use Tab Complete, this is the result that I want: `<div class=''>`

But this is the actual result: `<div class>`

The same thing happens for all attributes, such as `role` and `aria-label`.

Is there a setting that I can change, or some way to create a custom setting, that will include the equals symbol and the single quotes when I Tab Complete?

**Notes regarding incorrectly closing this question:**

This question was incorrectly closed and cited two duplicate questions:

1. [Automatic double quotes after '=' in Visual Studio Code when adding attributes in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770194/automatic-double-quotes-after-in-visual-studio-code-when-adding-attributes-i)
2. [How to make vscode autocomplete HTML tag's attribute with single quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897377/how-to-make-vscode-autocomplete-html-tags-attribute-with-single-quote)

Those questions were asking how to change the setting from double quotes to single quotes. My question was about troubleshooting the reason tab completion wasn't working. I have an answer that I want to post. Please re-open my question.

Comment: Check out VS Code's emmet feature: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Comment: I use emmet, and it works well when creating new elements. But if I need to add an attribute to an existing element, that is where I want the Tab Completion setting changed.

Comment: open your settings.json file and check if you changed any html settings. I'm particular interested in the value of your `html.completion.attributeDefaultValue` setting. still- I don't think any value of that setting can cause the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: hey @starball, your comment led me to the fix. I checked that setting and it was set to `doublequotes`. I toggled it to `singlequotes` and then the issue was fixed. Even when I toggled it back to `doublequotes` it still worked. I think I know what caused it. I'll post it as an answer when I get some time today or tomorrow.

Comment: I'm quite curious to know what the cause was... did you touch the `profile.booleanAttributes` emmet preference or something?

Comment: @starball sorry about the delay. They closed my question and I was waiting for it to re-open. I posted my answer below.

Comment: fyi: I was the one who closed it and reopened it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by toggling the value in this setting: `html.completion.attributeDefaultValue`

When I first went to my settings the value was set to `doublequotes`. I changed it to `singlequotes`. Then when I tested, the issue was fixed.

As an experiment I switched it back to `doublequotes` and the issue was still fixed.

Here's my theory:

My company uses Prettier and ESLint, and I suspect that the settings that were imposed by one or both of those conflicted with VSCode. Maybe some kind of cache bug. My company prefers single quotes and VSCode was set double quotes, so maybe that caused the issue. I'm not 100% sure, but now I know how to fix it if it happens again.

Comment: at the time of this comment, neither the fact that you are using prettier or eslint are present in your question post. you do not get a free pass on writing a question post with enough info to enable someone else to give a correct answer just because your write a self answer. please add that detail to your question post, and be more intentional about providing repro details in future questions.

Comment: I'm not looking for any kind of free pass or credit or anything like that. I was posting for future reference. I will do better next time, sir.

Comment: that wasn't supposed to come off accusational. it's just a fact. and you can do better now :) it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Install HTML 'Snippets' Extension
VSCode Extension ID: abusaidm.html-snippets

Edit: It has been deprecated.

Comment: That extension has been sunsetted.

Comment: Oh yes I see, because the VSCode HTML extension now implements those features.